# I have 2 MySql tables. How to get not all data from them in 1 sql query?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have 2 MySql tables. users with id's and username's ; streams with userId's and streamId's  How to get them as / join them into one table containing only 
`username | streamId` as SQL response? With one SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
select a.username, b.streamId
from names a, streams b
where a.userId = b.userId;
```

Comment: I think you might need a JOIN or something in there, but it seems like this would work.

Comment: Technically a comma between tables is a JOIN, its just old school syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
select tb1.username, tb2.streamid 
from tb1
inner join tb2 on tb2.userid = tb1.userid
```

The response above returns the same results, just contains an implicit join which my be slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.username, max(s.streamId) as streamId
from users u
inner join streams s on u.id = s.userId
group by u.username
```